# How to Create/Bake Maps for a Mesh that are Darker at the Bottom and Lighter at the Top

Tags: baking

Anyone know of a way to bake a map for an object that is dark at the bottom and becomes gradually lighter to the top, which is perfectly white? This would differ from a displacement map in that it would work on objects that fold over themselves, such as a tree, or a cave, or a bridge.

Thanks partner.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46748/create-a-displacement-map-from-high-res-terrain-to-use-on-low-poly-terrain/46756#46756

Comment: Yea, bu... "This would differ from a displacement map in that it would work on concave objects."

Comment: How does a displacement map fail for concave objects? Could you show an example? Please edit your question and provide some screenshots of what you are doing and why a displacement map doesn't work for you

Comment: You're right. What I really mean is objects that fold back over themselves, and wouldn't be able to be represented by a displacement map. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: So basically you want an unequivocal way to represent an infinitely complex 3D object with a 2D representation method. That sounds impossible, if I understand correctly. If someone were to crack that one up it would be a huge breakthrough for data interpretation and storage technologies.

Comment: It can be mapped like ambient occlusion map, if that makes it any easier.